# Serial Communication DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, serial

Пытаюсь написать dll на С++ для связи с com-портами, где dll будет использоваться через DllImport в С#.

Код пишется на примере [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

Для начала я попытался использовать данный пример в консольной аппликации :

```
static SerialPort^ _serialPort;

static void Main()

    _serialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM9");

    _serialPort->ReadTimeout = 500;
    _serialPort->WriteTimeout = 500;

    _serialPort->Open();

    _serialPort->WriteLine(String::Format("test"));

    _serialPort->Close();
```

все замечательно работает (вылавливаю сообщение test через putty), но при попытке использовать тот же код, но уже через dll:

```
static void Main()
{

    SerialPort^ _serialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM9");

    _serialPort->ReadTimeout = 500;
    _serialPort->WriteTimeout = 500;

    _serialPort->Open();

    _serialPort->WriteLine(String::Format("test"));

    _serialPort->Close();
}

int pOpen()
{
    PortChat::Main();
    return 1;
}
```

прилетает вот такое вот зло:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the port 'COM9' is
>   denied.

Собственно, что я делаю не так? (и вполне вероятно, что я делаю не так ВСЁ из-за не понимания)

Стоит добавить что часть C# (которая вызывает dll) работает через JavaScript.
То есть все это несчастье запускается через default.html.

Огромное спасибо.

Comment: А на тот момент 9-й порт вообще существует?

Comment: да существует. я все время это перепроверяю.

Comment: он именно ставит запрет на порт

Comment: Фигня какая-то... А нет ли, часом, AVASTа на машине?

Comment: нет.(win defender тоже отключен)

Comment: Может какой-то другой процесс в этот момент подключен к этому порту? Putty тот-же, например? Такое исключение обычно выводится в этом случае, т.к. нельзя иметь более одного подключения к одному COM-порту одновременно.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте может при компиляции dll "COM9" изменяется (бывают проблемы с кодировкой). Еще как вариант запустите приложение под администратором.

Comment: нет. к сожалению (или к счастью) не меняется при компиляции.

Comment: стоит добавить что часть C# (которая вызывает dll) работает через JavaScript. тоесть все это несчастье запускается через default.html.

Comment: На каком моменте вылетает Исключение, при открытии порта? Поставьте breakpoint до open и посмотрите поля _serialPort. Очень вероятно, что у вашего приложения нет прав.

Comment: _serialPort->Open();

Comment: Скорее всего Java не имеет прав доступа к порту. Как вариант можно попробовать чтобы с портом работала отдельная программа, а из java к ней приходили только сообщения и команды управления

Comment: на самом деле я уже рассматривал этот вариант,но мне показалось что это недостаточно элегантное решение. в любом случае спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пробовали запускать приложение от имени администратора? Может имеет смысл попробовать реализовать инициализацию последовательного порта средствами winApi (FileRead), там можно и параметры безопасности использовать. Вообще, лучше (наверно) использовать стандартный класс последовательного порта, присутствующий в .NET.